# Transformation of data for groups skewed in different directions

Tags: r, data-transformation, normality-assumption

I am running some data in R that is intended for multiple regression. However my data is not normally distributed. Most of my independant variables are continuous, however one is a catagorical factor containing two groups. The issue is that when looking at my dependent variable in terms of these groupings, there is a strong positive skew with one group and a strong negative skew with another group. I have included histogram images below to get an idea. Is there a transformation that I can apply that can help resolve this type of non-normality and how can I do this in R? I tried a log transformation, square root transformation, cube root transofrmation... no luck.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What about the residuals of your regression? Those are what matter.

Comment: Do you know anything about the process generating the data?

Comment: As @Dave commented: Data do not need to be normaly distributed for linear regression or else you could not even think of binary predictors.

Comment: Added residials via an edit. This has not been adjusted for outliers.

Comment: I would't worry based on these plots. For tests/confidence intervals, you could try bootstrapping.

Answer (score 0):

There is an R package called trafo that may give some ideas. I have not used it but it tests model assumptions using residuals (see @dave comment).

The dependent variable and group two look candidates for preprocessing by taking logarithms.

The Q-Q plot is not bad as far as these things go.
The heteroscedasity in the  residuals can be tested for using the Breusch–Pagan test.